# Create a RSS feed out of web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, rss

I want to be able to create a RSS feed out of this [webpage](http://footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/) I want the RSS feed to contain all the items that have their class as feed-item, I am using Wordpress anyone know anyway how to do it. I have used wp rss aggregator to create the page with all the feeds combined, but it doesn't actually create a combined rss feed.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a huge number of Wordpress plugins that can do what you are asking. Have you searched or tried any of them? Have a read of [**How to ask a question on StackOverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry about that. I have used wp rss aggregator to create the page with all the feeds combined, but it doesn't produce an actual RSS Feed

Comment: Actually  http://www.footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal/ this page also using RSS feed from any other website. So find different website for feed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand if you've already found the RSS feed of this page, wich is easily accessible through a RSS Autodiscovery plugin like RSS Icon in URL Bar (for Firefox). The URL is http://footballnewsdaily.net/category/arsenal/feed/

Or you can also use the WordPress Codex to find any feed you want generated by WordPress : https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

To autoblog it in WordPress, I usually use [FeedWorPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/) plugin which needs to create a Crohn task on your server. A bit technical but very customizable.

You can also use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/

Please note that your autoblog project can be percieved as "unfriendly" by FootBall News Daily.